# AngularJS ng-repeat not listing data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started learning AngularJS, but I am stuck on a problem. The `ng-repeat` is not looping through the users from the array. The list is just empty.

Here's my code.

*app.js*

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('dataCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.users = [ 
        { name: 'Max', age: 20 },
        { name: 'Tom', age: 42 },
        { name: 'Alex', age: 41 },
        { name: 'Thomas', age: 3 },
        { name: 'Andreas', age: 17 },
        { name: 'Richard', age: 11 } 
    ]
});
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp" lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Angular JS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Die Familie</h1>
        <table class="table" ng-controller="dataCtrl">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="users in user">
                    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.age}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ngRepeat` syntax is bass-ackwards - it's `obj in collection` not `collection in obj`

```
ng-repeat="user in users">
```

Comment: By the time I realized the issue, answer was there... _Too quick_...+1

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo ... it should be user in users... see [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MXMm6ZDfcn2fhb0mNFJT?p=preview)

```
   <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.age}}</td>
                </tr>
```

As a follow-up to the other comment, one recommend way is to use 'var vm=this' instead of $scope in your controller and 'controller as syntax' in your HTML. I updated the plunker.
Your HTML would look like:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <p>Hello {{vm.name}}!</p>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Die Familie</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in vm.users">
                    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.age}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Note that users become vm.users.

And your app:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = 'World';

   vm.users = [ 
        { name: 'Max', age: 20 },
        { name: 'Tom', age: 42 },
        { name: 'Alex', age: 41 },
        { name: 'Thomas', age: 3 },
        { name: 'Andreas', age: 17 },
        { name: 'Richard', age: 11 } 
    ];
});
```

Using both of those techniques avoid a lot of $scope issues as your code grow... especially with callbacks, functions, etc. where you end up with $scope meaning different things and it is a pain to debug. Here is an [article giving more info: "AngularJS's Controller As and the vm Variable" from John Papa](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) and his [Angular style guide is good to read too.](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the other answers above are why. May I suggest since you are learning you look into the "controller as" functionality and get rid of $scope. Anytime you learn something they show you the wrong way first.